# NSManagedObjectModel - create model dynamically

Tags: ios, ipad, nsmanagedobjectmodel

Can anyone point me to a tutorial on building the core data model dynamically in Xcode?
All tutorials I found are based on a static design but the apple documentation says it is possible to build the model programatically..sadly no example on that in apple documentation set.

Answer (score 3):

You have to init a `NSManagedObjectModel`, then for each entity in your model you create an `NSEntityDescription`, then create an `NSAttributeDescription` per attribute.  You can see a basic example from this post.

http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/45944-want-to-create-a-parent-entity-programmatically-in-manegedobjectmodel.html

Comment: Thanks. I found the link helpful.

Comment: @pooja-ios - if this answer solved your problem you need to hit the checkmark and accept it.